# How can I build a Docker image with Codebuild?

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr, docker-in-docker

I want to build a docker image from a Dockerfile, and publish this image to an AWS ECR (Docker registry).

In order to succeed, I need to have access to `docker build` and `docker push` from within the Codebuild container, which is problematic (installing docker inside a docker container causes errors such as `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`).

How would one proceed to do such a thing please? Is there any way to use codebuild to build Docker images from a Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution.
Follow [this link](https://medium.com/@whaleberry/using-aws-codebuild-to-build-image-from-docker-file-on-bitbucket-to-ecr-e004a455dd83) for the code, and don't forget to enable "Priviledged" in the "Environment" configuration screen.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a summary at least of the solution. The link might die at anytime making this post useless.

Comment: If someone is trying to find the settings, It's  Currently under      Build projetcs --> Edit -->Edit Environment -->Override image --> And select Privileged (Enable this flag if you want to build Docker images or want your builds to get elevated privileges.)

Answer (score 2):

Just clic the 'privileged mode' button in the CodeBuild settings
[privileged mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtEOz.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The [Docker sample for CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html) lists the following steps:

> - For Image, choose **aws/codebuild/standard:4.0**.
> - Because you use this build project to build a Docker image, select **Privileged**.

and provides the following note:

> **Note**
>
> By default, Docker containers do not allow access to any devices. Privileged mode grants a build project's Docker container access to all devices. For more information, see Runtime Privilege and Linux Capabilities on the Docker Docs website.

If you are still having trouble, the `PriviledgedMode` section of the CloudFormation docs for [AWS::CodeBuild::Project Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-environment.html) has the following steps for initializing the Docker daemon:

> You can initialize the Docker daemon during the install phase of your build by adding one of the following sets of commands to the install phase of your buildspec file:
>
> If the operating system's base image is Ubuntu Linux:
>
> `- nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --storage-driver=overlay&`
>
> `- timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"`
>
> If the operating system's base image is Alpine Linux and the previous command does not work, add the -t argument to timeout:
>
> `- nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --storage-driver=overlay&`
>
> `- timeout -t 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"`

Answer (score 0):

1. chose image ubuntu following:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html
2. Check on "Enable this flag if you want to build Docker images or want your builds to get elevated privileges."